# HTML How to overlay text on another text and verticaly centered

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and I am trying to make one text box over another. Illustration of what I am trying to achieve can be seen on the following link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe7Dn.png

I have found some piece of codes, which placed text over another like this

```
<div style="background:;position: relative;text-align:center;width:100%;">
<div style="color:yellow;position:relative;font-size: 50px;  text-align: center;"><strong>THIS IS PARAGRAPH THIS IS PARAGRAPH
    <div style="color:blue;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;">hello</div>
</div>
```

But I was unable to change it for what I need. Any advice? I feel it should not be difficult, but as my knowledge is limited for now I do not see the solution.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use CSS [::after](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) with [content](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) and [absolute positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for background text.

Try the below and tweak the values to suit you. Perhaps this will clean up the HTML too.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;800&display=swap');

*{
  padding: 0px;  
  margin: 0px;
 }

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

main::after {
  content: "DEALS";
  position: absolute; /* This will break text out of flow */
  z-index:-1;  /* This will place text right at the back */
  font-size: 120px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  
}

.first{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: blue;
}

.second{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <main>
    <h3 class="first" style="">The Journey Began</h3>
    <h1 class="second">EXPLORE THE BEST</h1>
  </main>
 </section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped me. I did not expect such a detailed approach and result matching the original. It also learned me a lot.

Comment: Hey @TomBr ! No worries. I'm glad I can help you. I should point out too that the pseudo element `::after` now becomes a child of main. This is why it is affected by flexbox :)

Answer (score 0):

The flex CSS property

```css
.container{
  background:#ddd;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

  
}
.text_bellow{
  color:yellow;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 150px;  
  text-align: center;
  
  }
.text_over{
  color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="text_bellow">
  <strong>DEALS</strong>

</div>
    <div class="text_over">
      <h3 class="first" style="">The Journey Began</h3>
      <h1 class="second">EXPLORE THE BEST</h1></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will definitely use it to compare Sam's answer to learn some new approaches.